# Pronunciation of one

Tags: pronunciation

I have the feeling that the word one is not always pronounced in all accents (but I cannot say which exactly) with the same vowel that cup or love. I believe that with accents where we pronounce cup [kɐp], we pronounce one [wɐn], but with accents where we prounouce cup differently, we often pronounce one [wɐn] or even [wän]. Is that a right feeling ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In accents in the north of England, where there happens to be no foot-strut split, a majority of speakers use /ʊ/, realised as [ö], in words like *love* and *cup*. This is the same vowel that RP speakers use for the word *soot*.

I have no idea if this is related in any way, but in many accents in the north of England there is a preference for the vowel /ɒ/, realised as [ɒ], for the word *one*, giving us the pronunciation [wɒn]. This word then rhymes with words such as *don* or *gone*. In contrast for a majority of RP speakers, this word, as noted by the Original Poster, rhymes with *sun* and would be transcribed as /wʌn/, [wɐn],

Notice that I said for the "majority of RP speakers" in the paragraph above. The renowned Longman Pronunciation Dictionary gives /wɒn/ as a variant of *one* and a minority of RP speakers do also use it (including me).

Comment: Does the same variation apply to "once"? Also, did you mean to say "a variant of *won*" or did you mean "a variant of *one*"?

Comment: @sumelic Yes, I believe so. (Definitely majority of RP speakers use strut there). Will have to double-check with some authentic northerners that they definitely use lot vowel there though, although I'm pretty sure they do. I'm an "RP" speaker, but still use lot vowel for "once".

Comment: But according to the California English vowel chart, this vowel is an open-mid central unrounded vowel, and in video from Californian, I have never heard one pronounced [w3n]. Excuse for IPA, but it is difficult on the iPhone

Comment: @pretuiol It is in SSBE (RP) English too! It's not that /ʌ / can be pronounced as [ɒ], it's that these varieties of British English can have /ɒ / instead of /ʌ / in the word *one*.  In other words there is no /ʌ / vowel (usually pronounced [ɐ], an open-mid central unrounded vowel) at all in these versions of these words :)

Comment: No in RP it is a near-open central unrouded vowel, and in California it is open-mid

Comment: @pretuiol Yes, that's right, it's near open in RP, got confused in my haste. My point is basically that it's not that those speakers use a different /ʌ/ in *one*, they have a different phoneme there.

Comment: Yes I have understood, but I have the feeling by people who have an open-mid vowel for cup use a near-open or even an open vowel for one

Comment: @pretuiol There is so much dialectal variation when it comes to the precise production of short vowels that you’re most likely right. Somewhere, there’s bound to be an accent that has an open-mid vowel for _cup_ but a near-open or open vowel for _one_. I have a South African colleague who has something like a near-open front vowel [æ] in _cup_, but what I would guess is probably a near-close or close-mid rounded central vowel [ʊ̈] or [ɵ] in _one_, which is the other way around, basically.

Comment: Foreigners, (I know only French speakers, but perhaps the others too) who don’t have near-open central unrounded vowel try to identify it with their known vowels, but, with French and maybe the others, we identify the vowel in strut or in sun with an open-mid front rounded vowel (like in fleurs) and the vowel in one with an open central unrounded vowel. Is there any raison if this is the same vowel ?

Comment: @pretuiol Which French vowel would that last one be?

Comment: The a in pas for example

Comment: @pretuiol Are you hearing this in London?

Comment: No, at my school. And for a distinction in american english, per example in this video https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=-P28LKWTzrI (the subject have no relation :D), at 1:16 he says one and he don’t pronounce it with the same vowel that in the others words with ʌ.

Comment: http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=sJupiMmsbx0 In this video, I have the impression that there are different vowels in some of these words. Per example between butter and one. This is an American pronunciation.

Comment: @pretuiol Yes, that's right. Vowels will change in terms of length and quality depending on what sounds are on either side of them, whether they're stressed, take the nuclear tome and so forth. The /ʌ/ in butter will be much shorter than the vowel in *ton*, for example. The vowel will also be nasalised in the word *ton* because of the /n/. There may also be some effect of lowering the vowel there too. I'm not aware of this from the literature, but it could be the case. I don't really study Amerian varieties of English, so I can't be of very much help there, I'm afraid :)

Comment: Oh thanks ! That’s the answer that I expected. I just wanted to know if it was normal and that the vowels and particularly this one could variate, although I couldn’t find any article about this. Thank you.

Comment: @pretuiol The different sounds that a vowel or consonant can have (but still be the same vowel/consonant) are called  allophones . So you might be able to find something if you search for "allophones of English vowels"

Comment: I couldn’t find anything about allophones of ʌ